# Search options problem with title:" "

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I think I found a bug in your search. When I do a search by title with double quotation, the spaces are not important if they are in the middle of the sentence but if they are at its end I'm redirected to the search option page.

Example:

```
// seaching for specific phrase
title:"Accessing parent objects while using a javascript module pattern variant"
```

<sup>[Demo link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:%22Accessing%20parent%20%20objects%20while%20using%20a%20javascript%20module%20pattern%20variant%22)</sup>

```
// extra spaces in between words (works fine)
title:"Accessing parent objects while using a javascript module pattern      variant"
```

<sup>[Demo link (spaces in middle)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:%22Accessing%20parent%20%20objects%20while%20using%20a%20javascript%20module%20pattern%20%20%20variant%22)</sup>

The above returns the expected results. However, the following redirects me to the search options page:

```
// same phrase but with trailing space (does not work)
title:"Accessing parent objects while using a javascript module pattern variant     "
```

<sup>[Demo link (space at the end)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:%22Accessing%20parent%20%20objects%20while%20using%20a%20javascript%20module%20pattern%20variant%20%22)</sup>

Comment: it smells in here like... a lot of spare time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above cases are handled gracefully as part of [the latest search changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), enjoy!